# Plone 4.0.5 workflow and permission

Tags: permissions, workflow, plone

I would be happy to get some advice on "workflow" type. Im not sure what is best - "Intranet/Extranet", "Simple Publication" or a third choice. Below are the types of folders and roles Im looking for:

- public folders: anonymous has "r".
- intranet folders: users has "r". Special users has "rw".
- private folders: only user in question and admin has "rw" (special users has also "rw")
- special folder: users that are member of a group has "rw".

Lastly, I do not understand this, users with e.g. "read", "edit" or "contribute" role can see user folders (marked as private), but also a test folder created as admin (marked as private)? PS Im using "Intranet/Extranet" type.

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Comment: Off-topic....SO is about programming questions...not about site configuration issues.

Comment: Do you know what Plone is?  If this is off-topic here, then we should pull _all_ the Plone tagged items out of here.  He's asking how to program his workflow, which is perfectly relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing Roles and Permissions in your question.  "read" and "write" would be permissions.  Reader, Editor, Contributor are Roles.

In an Internet/Extranet workflow, Anonymous users (a Role) would get Read access to Public content.

Private content would be accessible to users with the Owner or Manager (Administrator) role

"Internally Published" content is readable by users with Contributor, Editor, Manager, Member, Owner and Reader roles, but only editable by Managers.

"Internal" would correspond to the "Intranet" setting you want - where most users get read access, but you can give users the "Editor" role (using the sharing tab) to allow them to modify content.

Your "special" folders would simply be in the "Internal" state, but you would grant the Editor role to a group rather than a user.

Your last paragraph doesn't make much sense.  What do you mean by "created as admin"?  Created **by** admin?

In the Internet/Extranet workflow, the only difference between Private and Internal states is that "Members" can not view private content - but Editors can modify it and Contributors can view it.

Go to `/portal_workflow/intranet_workflow/states/manage_main` in your site to see the various Role-to-permission mappings

Comment: "In the Internet/Extranet workflow, the only difference between Private and Internal states is that "Members" can not view private content - but Editors can modify it and Contributors can view it."  Should read, "*Readers* can view it." Contributors can add new content.

Comment: Thanks Auspex and Laurence Rowe, sorry about the late answer. I think I managed to make it work now. All users are just Members. The groups have no roles at all. The role control is handled on the folder. This way I will not have an situation where members in group1 (having special rights in folder1) have access to folder2 (where only group2 should have full access).
Found a bug: after removing roles from a group, Im still having the roles on a given folder. When making a new folder, the test user in the group does not have access to the new folder (as exspected) - any suggestions? Thanks